# How to move cursor at first character positon using jquery mask plugin?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, jquery-plugins, jquery-mask

I have searched a lot and found out same kind of question but not exactly same and didn't find satisfactory answer. So thought, Should ask that more specific.
Using Jquery mask plugin, I would like my cursor at the beginning always no matter which positon I click. If I click into that textbox, cursor should be at the beginning. with my below code. wherever I click into the textbox, cursor gets that particular positon. How to avoid that?

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="tbMobile" CssClass="ContactNumber" runat="server" onfocus="GetPhoneMask();" MaxLength="15" placeholder="555-555-5555" ValidationGroup="Application"></asp:TextBox>

function GetPhoneMask() {
        $(".ContactNumber").mask("999-999-9999", { autoclear: false });
    }
```

Updated: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Live link https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gipb8h

I changed the phone class name.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebFormsPW._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.phone_us').mask('(000) 000-0000');
        })
        //took out
        //function GetPhoneMask() {
        //    $(".ContactNumber").mask("999-999-9999", { autoclear: false });
        //}
    </script>
    <%--    took out onfocus="GetPhoneMask();"--%>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbMobile" CssClass="phone_us" runat="server" MaxLength="15" placeholder="555-555-5555" ValidationGroup="Application"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Thanks @kblau for the answer. It really helped and I realise I am getting underline so it does help to select pointer position, I set empty placeholder $('.ContactNumber').mask('999-999-9999', { autoclear: false, 'placeholder': '' }); it worked.